# Macro expansion in C — retrieving unsigned 32 bit word

Tags: c, types, macros, struct, buffer

How does the following snippet work? What is IN? Eclipse says that IN stands for 'macro expansion':

```
 UWORD32 (*get_u32)(IN UWORD8 *buffer_ptr);    /* Gets unsigned 32bit word   */
                                           /* from the buffer */
```

This above code is part of a struct. and is used like this.

```
struct my struct s;
UWORD8* buf;

s->get_u32(buf);
```

How does it work?

Comment: Also mention System (Linux/window?)... I search 'IN' through Library files in Linux, didn't find such the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that `IN` is `#define`d somewhere as `const`:

```
#define IN const    // input parameters are const
```

`get_u32` is just a function pointer - the function takes a single parameter (a pointer to a `UWORD8`) and returns a `UWORD32`.

Comment: The definition of IN is this: /* Parameter declared with IN, will be used to hold INput value */
#define  IN  
there is no const...what does this mean?

Comment: It doesn't make much difference to the meaning - it's just a notational convenience. The `IN` is effectively just a comment in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can even declare IN as "nothing"

```
#define IN
#define OUT
```

In this case it will just make your code more readable :)

```
void func ( IN param_t param1,         /* INPUT PARAM */
            IN param_t param2,         /* INPUT PARAM */
            OUT param_t *param3);      /* OUTPUT PARAM */
```